# How to get sound through headphones or external monitor by default (XPS-13)

Tags: windows-10, audio, displayport, dell-xps, realtek-hd-audio

When I plug my Dell XPS-13 into an external monitor via DisplayPort, I want the sound to come through the monitor, not the internal speakers.

When I plug a headset into the XPS-13 (whether or not it's attached to a monitor), I want sound to come through the headphones.

i.e. I want the following priority:

> 1. Headphones
> 2. Monitor speakers
> 3. Internal speakers

So I set the default audio device, bit I can only select "Speakers / Headphones (Realtek Audio)", OR the monitor's audio, as default.

Problem is, this treats the internal speakers the same as the headphones, since it's a combines "Speakers / Headphones" option, so I don't get the desired behaviour.

How can I get this to automatically switch without manually changing the sound device each time?

Answer (score 0):

Plugging in headphones should mute the internal speakers does it not? If not I'd reinstall the Dell sound drivers & their should be an app to check a couple settings in, but it only controllers the realtek (internal or headphones)

I'm personally not aware how to change the priority as you want, but hopefully someone else will speak up to a SW utility that does that :)

Comment: Yes it does mute the internal speakers, so if I'm using internal speakers it's fine. The question is how to get it to switch from monitor speakers to headphones when I plug them in.